# Replace key-value pair in query string with Apache2

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I am trying to set a simple replacement in my URL query strings.

I have an absolute path in my query string I would like to be replaced by a custom string.

```
FROM  http://acme.com/a/path?file=DIR/this.file&foo=2
  TO  http://acme.com/a/path?file=/long/absolute/path/to/this.file&foo=2
```

These are my directives:

```
# [sudo a2enmod rewrite]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)file=DIR(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/a/path /a/path?%1file=/long/absolute/path/to%2
```

With such a configuration, replacement does not work, `DIR` passes through.
I configured a `LogLevel` to `trace1` in my Apache2 configuration but I get nothing in my `access.log` and no useful feedback in `error.log`.

The question is:

[image]

---

**References**:

- https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html

Comment: As in the best answer below: `RewriteEngine` is `Off` by default, had to turn it `On` + add the suggested flags and voilá.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me(I've added flags R and L):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)file=DIR(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/a/path /a/path?%1file=/long/absolute/path/to%2 [R,L]
```

See also https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

Comment: Thank you Sergio, but flags don't help here... It just does not replace the condition. In my case, this is the query-string of a CGI call, not sure if this changes things.

Comment: if error.logs empty then rewriteCond pattern or RewriteRule pattern not found.

Comment: when you place `RewriteRule ^a/path /a/path?uri=%{REQUEST_URI}&query=%{QUERY_STRING} [R,L]` to .htaccess, what are you getting as result when sending your request?

Comment: Got it: I did not turn on the engine! GOSH. Sergio, I also had to add the flags you suggested to make it work so I suggest you add the `RewriteEngine On` directive in your answer and I'll choose it !